# What is the difference between "is not null" and "!= null"?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

With the release of C# 9.0, the *negated null constant* pattern was introduced.

The documentation for [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns) states:

> Beginning with C# 9.0, you can use a negated null constant pattern to check for non-null, as the following example shows:
>
> ```cs
> if (e is not null)
> {
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Is there any difference between `e is not null` and `e != null`, besides the syntax?

Comment: [Constant pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#constant-pattern): "The compiler guarantees that no user-overloaded equality operator == is invoked ..."

Comment: Its funny, the text you copied for your question, is one line below the answer you were looking for

Comment: Ha!! Got the answer then :) Thanks, I didn't spot that.

Comment: Essentially the compiler will convert it to `(object)e!= null` which assures no pesky overloaded equality operators are involved

Comment: _"pesky overloaded equality operators"_ That's what we should call them. Always.

Answer (score 57):

The main difference between `e != null` and `e is not null` is the way the the compiler executes the comparison.

[Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#constant-pattern): *"The compiler guarantees that **no** user-overloaded equality operator == is invoked when expression x is null is evaluated."*

**Bottom Line:** If you are writing code that you don't want to depend on someone's implementation of the `!=` and `==` operators, use `is null` and `is not null` because it is safer.

See the following example:

```
public class TestObject
{
  public string Test { get; set; }

  // attempt to allow TestObject to be testable against a string
  public static bool operator ==(TestObject a, object b)
  {
    if(b == null)
      return false;
    
    if(b is string)
      return a.Test == (string)b;

    if(b is TestObject)
      return a.Test == ((TestObject)b).Test;

    return false;
  }

  public static bool operator !=(TestObject a, object b)
  {
    if(b == null)
      return false;
    
    if(b is string)
      return a.Test != (string)b;

    if(b is TestObject)
      return a.Test != ((TestObject)b).Test;

    return false;
  }
}
```

If you have code that needs to ensure that an object isn't null, using `is not null` will give you better results with `TestObject` than using `!= null` because the overload of the `==`/`!=` operators is a little odd.

**Console example 1:**

```
TestObject e = null;

if(e == null)
  Console.WriteLine("e == null");

if(e is null)
  Console.WriteLine("e is null");
```

Output: `e is null`

**Console example 2:**

```
TestObject e = new TestObject();

if(e != null)
  Console.WriteLine("e != null");

if(e is not null)
  Console.WriteLine("e is not null");
```

Output: `e is not null`

Neither overloaded operator is implemented "correctly" so the Console never outputs `e == null` or `e != null`.

Answer (score 19):

The only difference (besides the syntax) is, that the compiler guarantees that no user-overloaded operator is called when using `is not null` instead of `!= null` (or `is null` instead of `== null`).

From [operator overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading):

> A user-defined type can overload a predefined C# operator. That is, a
> type can provide the custom implementation of an operation in case one
> or both of the operands are of that type. The [Overloadable operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading#overloadable-operators)
> section shows which C# operators can be overloaded.

Comment: Can you please expand on what you mean by "user-overloaded operator"?

Comment: In C# you can overload operators to alter the default handling of them. For more information, see [the official documentation for operator overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading)

Comment: This isn't the **only** difference - the compiler will not let you use `x is null` or `x is not null` when dealing with structs - it will issue an error: *CS0037: Cannot convert null to '<your type>' because it is a non-nullable value type*, but it will let you use `x == null` or `x != null` (with a warning - *CS0472: The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type '<your type>' is never equal to 'null'*).

Comment: It seems like `structs` are a special case then for which the `is null` and `is not null` patterns cannot be used. But this was not the question. If OP got an error for `is not null`, the question would have been another. You can however edit my answer if you want and add this special case as an info.